# Merge or combine an array like this? on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multi-dimensional PHP array (*below*).

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2] => one@example.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [4] => two@example.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [3908] => twenty@example.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2548] => eleven@example.com
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [3099] => ten@example.com
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [5283] => six@example.com
        )

)
```

---

I was wondering how could I merge? or combine? or simply do it like this using PHP (*below*).

---

```
Array
(
    [2] => one@example.com
    [4] => two@example.com
    [3908] => twenty@example.com
    [2548] => eleven@example.com
    [3099]  => ten@example.com
    [5283]  => six@example.com
)
```

Help

Answer (score 3):

You can "promote" the second level elements to first level elements via [call_user_func_array()](http://de.php.net/call_user_func_array). And while array_merge() re-indexes the array, [array_replace()](http://php.net/array_replace) does not but retains the original keys which makes this a one-liner:

```
$a = call_user_func_array('array_replace', $a);
```

test:

```
<?php
$a = array (
  array (2 => 'one@example.com'),
  array (4 => 'two@example.com'),
  array (3908 => 'twenty@example.com'),
  array (2548 => 'eleven@example.com'),
  array (3099 => 'ten@example.com'),
  array (5283 => 'six@example.com'),
);
$a = call_user_func_array('array_replace', $a);
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: This does the trick, but it's important to note that array_replace() only exists since PHP 5.3.0 (20090630).

Answer (score 0):

Simply go through the array and store to another.

```
$a = array( 0 => array(1) , 1=> array(3) );
$another=array();
foreach ($a as $k=>$v){    
    foreach ($v as $y=>$z){
        $another[$k]=$z;
    }    
}
print_r($another);
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily slow, and is big O of n^2. You can simply concatenate arrays, which will retain keys and values.

Comment: You lose the keys relying on array_push. You'd have to replace that with $another[$y] = $z instead.

Comment: I didn't feel it was fair to downvote this answer, though it may not be elegant, the thought was there as demonstrated by the correction. Even though its not the most elegant, it does do the job. I'm +1 to bring it from -1 to 0.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
foreach( $old_arr as $old )
{
    $key = key( $old[0] );
    $new[ $key ] = $old[0][$key];
}
```

EDIT: Never mind didn't realize previous answer was corrected.

Comment: This won't work because it assumes the child array values are keyed on 0, when none of those in the example are.