# How to Merge Arrays within an Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] = Charcoal
    [1] = Natural Gas
    [2] = Combo
)
Array
(
    [0] = Charcoal
    [1] = Propane
    [2] = Combo
)
Array
(
    [0] = Charcoal
    [1] = Propane
    [2] = Natural Gas
    [3] = Combo
)
Array
(
    [0] = Natural Gas
)
Array
(
    [0] = Natural Gas
    [1] = Propane
)
Array
(
    [0] = Propane
)
Array
(
    [0] = 660 sq. inches
)
Array
(
    [0] = 740 sq. inches
)
Array
(
    [0] = 761 sq. inches
)
Array
(
    [0] = 788 sq. inches
)
Array
(
    [0] = 792 sq. inches
)
```

my desire is for it to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] = Charcoal
    [1] = Propane
    [2] = Natural Gas
    [3] = Combo
    [4] = 660 sq. inches
    [5] = 740 sq. inches
    [6] = 761 sq. inches
    [7] = 788 sq. inches
    [8] = 792 sq. inches
)
```

I've just recentely learned how to use arrays. So I tried array Merge.. that didnt work.

Comment: Potential repeat question, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141566/merge-or-combine-an-array-like-this-on-php?rq=1

Comment: Create a new array, iterate through all your arrays and for each of their values if doesn't exist in the new array then add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) on [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge):

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data);
```

So your though is correct, but you need a bit tricker way to call it (because you need to pass your array as parameters to `array_merge()`)

Also, note, that merging is done without unique check on values. Thus, if you want to get rid of duplicates, apply [`array_uniqie()`](http://php.net/array_unique):

```
$result = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data));
```

Check the [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/UdJ3B).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is to combine all your elements into one array, but only keep each unique element once. Since you have an array of arrays, you need to call [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) with each sub-array as a parameter. You can do this using [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
$merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $myArray);
```

Then use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) to keep each element only once:

```
$merged = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $myArray));
```